# What is the quotient group of $O_2$/$SO_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on this as a challenge problem, but I have never worked with a quotient group outside of modular values in the integers.

Answer (score -1):

$SO_2$ is, by definition,  the kernel of the homomorphism $O_2\to \Bbb F^\times$,  $A\mapsto \det A$, which happens to be onto.

Comment: Never seen an orthogonal matrix with determinant $17$...